# Assistance troubleshooting failed exchange 2016 SSL certificate request using cmdlet

Tags: exchange-server

I am trying to request an SSL certificate from my internal certificate authority using cmdlet.

I am running exchange 2016. I can only make the SSL certificate request using cmdlet. One of the gentlemen from another forum provided me with the cmdlet that I need to run to request the SSL certificate. He replaced the pertinent information with my information. My domain name is photonicss.com. The server is the domain controller. The host name is photonics-dc02. The certificate authority in installed on the domain controller.

$txtrequest = New-ExchangeCertificate -Server "photonics-dc02" -GenerateRequest -FriendlyName "Exchange Certificate photonicss.com" -PrivateKeyExportable $true -SubjectName "c=US, s=Bew York, l=The Bronx, o=photonicss, ou=IT, cn=mail. photonicss.com" -DomainName "mail.photonicss.com ,autodiscover.photonicss.com,owa.photonics.com,smtp.photonicss.com,servernames.photonicss.com"

[image: Screenshot of error]

When I run the above cmdlet, I get the error shown in the screen shot.

This is the error message:

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DomainName'. Cannot convert value "mail.photonicss.com
,autodiscover.photonicss.com,owa.photonics.com,smtp.photonicss.com,servernames.photonicss.com" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Data.MultiValuedProperty`1[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpDomainWithSubdomains]". Error: "Failed to
convert mail.photonicss.com
,autodiscover.photonicss.com,owa.photonics.com,smtp.photonicss.com,servernames.photonicss.com from System.String to
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpDomainWithSubdomains. Error: Error while converting string 'mail.photonicss.com
,autodiscover.photonicss.com,owa.photonics.com,smtp.photonicss.com,servernames.photonicss.com' to result type
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpDomainWithSubdomains: "mail.photonicss.com
,autodiscover.photonicss.com,owa.photonics.com,smtp.photonicss.com,servernames.photonicss.com" isn't a valid SMTP
domain."
+ CategoryInfo         : InvalidData: (:) [New-ExchangeCertificate], ParameterBindin...mationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-ExchangeCertificate
+ PSComputerName       : exvm1.photonicss.com

I am running this cmdlet on the domain controller. I have exchange management shell installed on the domain controller. The exchange management shell says I am connected to exvm1,  which is the exchange server. Can someone assist me troubleshooting the cmdlet. I think it's the only way I can request the SSL certificate with exchange 2016.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command. The DomainName property does not accept a string so you need to remove the quotes and ensure there are no spaces between the commas.

```
$txtrequest = New-ExchangeCertificate -Server "photonics-dc02" -GenerateRequest -FriendlyName "Exchange Certificate photonicss.com" -PrivateKeyExportable $true -SubjectName "c=US, s=Bew York, l=The Bronx, o=photonicss, ou=IT, cn=mail. photonicss.com" -DomainName mail.photonicss.com,autodiscover.photonicss.com,owa.photonics.com,smtp.photonicss.com,servernames.photonicss.com
```

More information about the New-ExchangeCertificate cmdlet can be found here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-exchangecertificate?view=exchange-ps